# MySQL insert rows using from select statment while incrementing a a user definable order

Tags: mysql

What I am doing here is turning a quote into a PO, this is just one the queries I'm using to do this. The primary key of `router` is `RN`, a unique key in this table is `Line Order`. I'm using `Line Order` to allow the user to define the order of the rows in `router`. Since `RN` is set to auto_increment I don't have to worry about that. The problem is `Line Order`
 on the `router`. I select multiple rows from `rfq_operations` for inserting into `router`, but it gives all the rows the same `Line Order` value, I need them to increment 1 from `MAX(router.Line Order)`

```
INSERT INTO `router`(`Work Order`, `Line Order`, `Estimated Time`,`Estimated Time Unit`, `Work Center`, `Work Description`, `Work Instruction`)
SELECT ?,(SELECT 1+IFNULL(MAX(`Line Order`),1) FROM `router`),CEIL(((`rfq_operations`.`Program Time`+`rfq_operations`.`Setup Time`+(`rfq_operations`.`Run Time`*(?/`rfq_operations`.`Conversion`)))/60))
    ,'Hours',`rfq_operations`.`Work Center`,`workcenter`.`Information`,`rfq_operations`.`Instructions`
FROM `rfq_operations`
LEFT JOIN `workcenter`
ON `rfq_operations`.`Work Center`=`workcenter`.`RN`
WHERE `rfq_operations`.`RFQ Line`=?
ORDER BY `rfq_operations`.`Line Order`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select` query is run then the results are inserted into the final table.  So, you only get one value.  You don't see changes to the table during the `select`.

In any case, you can do what you want with variables.  Your query is a bit complicated, but here is the idea:

```
insert into router(col1, . . .)
    select (@rn := @rn + 1), . . .
    from . . . cross join
         (select @rn := coalesce(max(`Line Order`), 0) from router) vars;
```

This initializes the `@rn` variable to the maximum value.  It then increments it for each row in the subquery.

That said, the proper thing to do is to have an auto-incrementing key for this.  Just define `Line Order` as an auto-incrementing primary key and the database will increment values for you.

Comment: The reason why I cannot make `Line order` auto incrementing is because RN already auto Increments and is used to relate row data to data in other tables